# Quando não escrever nada, não aparecer "Digite um nome"

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ionic

Eu estou mexendo num aplicativo feito no Ionic. Nele, quando procuro uma foto no Google e a seleciono, o campo nome é preenchido com a palavra que fez a busca. Agora, quando seleciono uma imagem do celular, o campo pra colocar o nome já fica em branco pra colocar qualquer nome, mas pode deixar em branco se quiser. O problema é quando deixa em branco e manda compartilhar, a imagem gerada fica com o nome "Digite um nome".

O código:

```
         <div class="col-50 block text-right panel" style="margin-right: 2px;position:relative;" ng-click="showOptions(image1)">
            <div ng-show="!shouldShowImage(image1.src)" style="text-align: center;margin:15px;">
              Selecione a sua foto ou a foto de um amigo!
              <div>
                <a class="button button-icon ion-camera larger" ng-click="takePicture(image1)"></a>
                <a class="button button-icon ion-images larger" ng-click="chooseFromGalery(image1)"></a>
                <a class="button button-icon ion-search larger" ng-click="searchImage(image1)"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<ion-content direction="xy" locking="false" scroll="true" ng-show="shouldShowImage(image1.src)" ng-click="showHideCleanButton(image1)">
                <img id="image1" ng-src="{{image1.src}}">
            </ion-content>-->
            <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" min-zoom="1" max-zoom="3" ng-show="shouldShowImage(image1.src)" ng-click="showHideCleanButton(image1)">
              <img id="image1" ng-src="{{image1.src}}" style="height:100vmin;">
            </ion-scroll>
              <div class="imagelabel" ng-show="shouldShowImage(image1.src)">
                  <!--{{image1.textname == null ? "digite um nome..." : image1.textname}}-->
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite um nome..." ng-model="image1.textname" style="text-align: center;">
              </div>
            <div style="position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;" ng-show="showClearButton(image1)">
              <button ng-click="clean(image1)" class="button button-energized"><i class="icon ion-close-circled"></i></button>
            </div>
              <!--<div id='parent' style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
                  <div id='child' style="width:100px; margin:0px auto;">
                      centered div
                  </div>
              </div>-->
          </div>
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não conheço este ionic, mas parece que aqui `<!--{{image1.textname == null ? "digite um nome..." : image1.textname}}-->` está usando um operador ternário fazendo com que quando o nome da imagem não existir (null), para que ele seja "digite um nome"... Tenta mudar este texto pra false por exemplo, ou algum texto de seu interesse ("sem título" p.ex...).

Comment: Coloquei false, mas aí o campo pra escrever o texto pra colocar o nome some. Não tem outra forma?

Comment: Eu não conheço esse ionic, mas experimenta retirar este trecho inteiro: `<!--{{image1.textname == null ? "digite um nome..." : image1.textname}}-->`  e diz o que aconteceu...

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" id="txName" placeholder="Digite o nome" ng-model="image1.textname" style="text-align: center;">
```

Quando for disparar a função para salvar a foto, no começo dela você faz

```
$('#txName').prop('placeholder','');
```

ou

```
$('#txName').attr('placeholder','');
```

Para ele remover apenas no momento correto e não influenciar o resultado final que é a imagem.

Comment: Mas precisa fica escrito "Digite um nome" para o usuário ver que tem um campo que possa escrever o nome.

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, da uma olhada, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Esse dois comandos que vou escolher, eu jogo no controllers.js?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,
  O Ionic (melhor, o AngularJs!) preza por não alterar o DOM via controller.
  Minha sugestão é que você controle os placeholders ou nomes de arquivos via variáveis de escopo.
  Abaixo segue um exemplo de um select que, quando alterado, muda o texto de placeholder de uma textarea:

Template.html:

```
<select ng-model="tipoUsuario" ng-change="userChanged()" >
   <!-- options... -->
</select>
<textarea placeholder="{{dicaDeTexto}}"></textarea>
```

Controller.js:

```
$scope.userChanged = function( ) {
    $scope.dicaDeTexto = $scope.tipoUsuario.dica;
};
```